# change form action dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I think this question has been asked a few times and I did find a few on google too.

However I am not trying to change the whole form action. I just need to change it partially.

Here is what I mean:

I have the following form:

```
    <form action="order.php?add=<?php echo $product_name; ?>&amp;price=<?php echo $price; ?>&amp;qty=1" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="qty"  size="12"   />
        <input type="submit" class="button2" name="buttonadd" id="button" value="Add to cart" />
   </form>
```

what I need to do is to change the `qty=1` in the form action so it reflects the `<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="qty"  size="12"   />` value!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds a bit odd, why do you want to do that? Can you not just use the `$_POST['qty']` value in your PHP page?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Your data is being sent via POST and you are modifying this to a get variable? So in a sence you are sending GET parameters and POST parameters

Comment: Don't pass value like this rather use hidden fields.

Comment: Mixing GET and POST type variables is never a good idea.

Comment: because its a quantity of the product so i want to give the users the option of changing the quantity.

Comment: Let them change it, but just use the POST variable. #

Comment: $('form').attr('action', 'setNewAction.php');

Comment: guys this is not going to be integrated into any payment gataway. everything is internal.. so please answer the actual question please.

Comment: Guys, this user never indicated that he was using PHP. It may as well be a call to a 3rd party script that he can't / doesn't want to hack around with.

Comment: @PelletenCate `action="order.php` could indicate otherwise

Comment: Whoops, @MonkeyZeus, missed that. ;-)

Comment: @PelletenCate haha I figured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Form method to 'get' (the thing that's now POST)

```
<form action="order.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="<?php echo $product_name ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $price ?>" />
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="qty"  size="12"   />
    <input type="submit" class="button2" name="buttonadd" id="button" value="Add to cart" />
</form>
```

And there you have it! :)

(I also removed the other URL parameters and put them into hidden inputs. In my opinion, this is a much cleaner way to do this.)

Comment: If OP wants to switch methods then maybe show this as well `$('form').attr('method', 'GET');`

Comment: I thought I had to use POST as i was actually posting the data from one page to another! anyway your suggestion worked. thumbs up... P.S. i do want to hack around with the script however my knowledge is limited and that is why i ask questions here every time i pump into an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In plain JS you could do :

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('qty').addEventListener('input', function(event) {
        var action = this.form.getAttribute('action','');
        action = action.replace(/qty=\d+/, 'qty=' + this.value);
        this.form.setAttribute('action',action);
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lw7m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**OP requested something specific.**

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UjGA/1/)

```
$('#qty').change( function() {
       var value = $(this).val();
       $('#form').attr('action', 'order.php?qty=' + value);
    alert($('#form').attr('action'));
});
```

---

```
<form id="form" action="order.php?qty=1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" class="qty"  size="12"   />
    <input type="submit" class="button2" name="buttonadd" id="button" value="Add to cart" /></form>
```

---

I've added `id="form"`.

**I don't agree with this method, and you should use POST, but OP asked for it;**

> guys this is not going to be integrated into any payment gataway. everything is internal.. so please answer the actual question please.

I've edited the form action just so we can demo it on JsFiddle. By all means, add in the PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

Here an alternate way that working perfectly [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPAcw/1/)

```
 $("#qty").keyup(function (){
   var first=$("form").attr("action").substring(($("form").attr("action").indexOf("qty")),0)
   $("form").attr("action",first+"qty="+$(this).val());
   console.log($("form").attr("action"))
 });
```